# numpy is not multi-thread

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

My setup:

- Python 3.5, compiled and installed to somewhere in my home directory;
- OpenBLAS, already installed in `/usr/local` (I compiled my own OpenBLAS too, but the problem persisted)
- Numpy, checked out from github, edited `site.cfg` to locate OpenBLAS, and installed in a virtualenv.
- I have nothing else installed in this virtualenv or on this interpreter.

Problem: Numpy is very slow and always uses a single thread. `OMP_NUM_THREADS` is not respected. My test case (matrix multiplication) takes 16 sec, regardless of whether `OMP_NUM_THREADS` is set.

There is also a Python 2.7 interpreter, with its numpy linked to the same OpenBLAS installation. Multi-threading works on that interpreter, and the same test case takes 2.3 sec if `OMP_NUM_THREADS` is not set, or 2.5 sec if `OMP_NUM_THREADS=8`, or 13 sec if `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`.

Also strangely, I have to specify the location of the OpenBLAS library in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable in order to use my setup, even though I have provided the path in `site.cfg` before I compiled numpy. This is not necessary if I use the numpy in Python 2. What steps did I miss?